# Using counters in macros to manage Beamer overlays

Tags: beamer, macros, counters

I have a very complex Tikz figure that is uncovered piece by piece during my presentation.  While tweaking the presentation I decided to change the order of things being uncovered and due to the large amount of \onslide commands it is a pain to get it right.  In order to help the situation I tried to create the following two macros:

```
\newcommand*{\BeamerCounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
    \newcounter{#1}}{}}

\newcommand*{\BeamerNext}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1#2}{%
    \stepcounter{#1}   
    \newcommand*{#1#2}{\the#1}}{}}
```

The idea is that at the top level of my document I would do something like:

```
\BeamerCounter{Fig}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
```

So that in my figure I can use:

```
\onslide<\FigPart1>{ .. }
\onslide<\FigPart2>{ .. }
\onslide<\FigPart1, \FigPart2>{ .. }
```

Minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand*{\BeamerCounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
    \newcounter{#1}}{}}

\newcommand*{\BeamerNext}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1#2}{%
    \stepcounter{#1}
    \newcommand*{#1#2}{\the#1}}{}}

\BeamerCounter{Fig}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<FigPart1-> item1
    \item<FigPart2-> item2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following errors:

```
t.tex:12: You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
t.tex:12: leading text: \BeamerCounter{Fig}
t.tex:12: Missing $ inserted.
t.tex:12: leading text: \BeamerCounter{Fig}
t.tex:12: Missing \begin{document}.
t.tex:12: leading text: \BeamerCounter{Fig}
t.tex:13: You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
t.tex:13: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
t.tex:13: Missing number, treated as zero.
t.tex:13: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
t.tex:13: Missing control sequence inserted.
t.tex:13: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
t.tex:13: You already have nine parameters.
t.tex:13: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
t.tex:13: You can't use `the letter F' after \the.
t.tex:13: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
t.tex:14: You can't use `\spacefactor' in math mode.
t.tex:14: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
t.tex:14: Missing number, treated as zero.
t.tex:14: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
t.tex:14: Missing control sequence inserted.
t.tex:14: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
t.tex:14: You already have nine parameters.
t.tex:14: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
t.tex:14: You can't use `the letter F' after \the.
t.tex:14: leading text: \BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}
t.tex:15: Missing $ inserted.
```

Comment: Around the code for the two `\newcommand`'s you need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several weaknesses in your code.

1. You want to use the macro `\@ifundefined`, so the code must be surrounded by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` as explained in [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/)
2. `\newcommand*{#1#2}{\the#1}` is wrong for several reasons; suppose you do `\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}`; then TeX would try

   ```
   \newcommand*{FigPart1}{\the Fig}
   ```
3. Of course `\newcommand*{FigPart1}` is illegal, but you can't solve this by saying `\newcommand*{\#1#2}` in the definition, because this would be illegal as well: `\#` is the name of a token.
4. Also `\the#1` wouldn't refer to `\theFig`, because `\the` is already a token.
5. You don't want `\theFig` anyway, but the *current* value of `\theFig`.
6. Even if this worked, `\item<FigPart2->` wouldn't do what you expect, because `FigPart2` is not the name of a command.

Here's an amended version.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\BeamerCounter}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}{%
    \newcounter{#1}}{}}

\newcommand*{\BeamerNext}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1#2}{%
    \stepcounter{#1}%
    % \edef to get the current value
    \expandafter\edef\csname#1#2\endcsname{\the\value{#1}}}{}%
}
\newcommand{\BC}[1]{\@nameuse{#1}} % for using the newly defined command
\makeatother

\BeamerCounter{Fig}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part1}
\BeamerNext{Fig}{Part2}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<\BC{FigPart1}-> item1
    \item<\BC{FigPart2}-> item2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This made my life so much easier! And thank you for explaining what was wrong with the way I was trying to do it.

Comment: @DavidHolm You're welcome!